# Write variable products ( woocommerce ) in php

Tags: php, woocommerce, codeigniter-3

I have an online shop website with CodeIgniter framework. The client side is almost done and now I'm working on Add Product in admin panel.

We have 2 types of products (Variable Products & Invariable Products) and I have problem with Variable type. The database has 5 tables:

First table : Attribute Items

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Color       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Size        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Second table : Variable Attribute Items

```
+----+------------+-------------------+
| ID | Product_id | Attribute_item_id |
+----+------------+-------------------+
|  1 |          3 |                 1 |
|  2 |          3 |                 2 |
+----+------------+-------------------+
```

Third Table : Variable Attribute Values

```
+----+-----------------------+-------+
| ID | Variable_attr_item_id | Value |
+----+-----------------------+-------+
|  1 |                     1 | Red   |
|  2 |                     1 | Blue  |
|  3 |                     1 | Black |
|  4 |                     2 | Small |
|  5 |                     2 | Large |
+----+-----------------------+-------+
```

And 2 other tables.

I cannot change the table structure because it works fine on the client side (with added information manually).

And values or items can be more than these like **Models** in **Items** Or **Medium** in **Values**

How to receive the information like below:

**1,4 (Red,Small)


1,5 (Red,Large)


2,4 (Blue,Small)


2,5 (Blue,Large)


3,4 (Black,Small)


3,5 (Black,Large)**

How would I go about making this work?

Comment: a simple `join`?